# common logarithm and natural logarithm in calculus

Tags: calculus

Question is $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}2(\operatorname{cosec} x)^{17}dx$ and the right option is
$\int_0^{log (\sqrt2 +1)}2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16} du $

But on solving we get answer as $\int_0^{ln (\sqrt2 +1)}2(e^u+e^{-u})^{16} du $.

My question how are they both the same? Thanks

Comment: Your text probably treats $\log$ as $\ln$. Without not much else we cannot say. (By the way, `$\csc$` looks nicer for the cosecant, note the backslash.)

Comment: Even an online calculator treats the integral boundary of the log as ln. Why?

Comment: It should be using log to base $e$ which is usually written as $ln$ or $log_e$. However some books use $log$ to mean log base $e$ as @SeanRoberson indicated

Comment: Because the natural logarithm  $\ln$ is [more natural](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1499094/21813) than any other choice of base.

Comment: Grownups use $\log$ for the natural logarithm.